# sklearn.cross_validation is deprecated warning triggered by sklearn.model_selection

Tags: scikit-learn, anaconda

When I first changed my code to "model_selection", the warnings quit. Over the weekend I updated Anaconda and now any import of sklearn triggers the "cross_validation" warning.

I've found several samples of this error on the net, none addressing this specific issues. It if has been, it's due to my old brain not being able properly form the question. Apologies in advance. Clarity greatly appreciated.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# tpot pipeline

from tpot import TPOTClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import numpy as np
from numpy import loadtxt
```

Comment: So you are saying that the code snippet you have posted here, shows the warning? Try the imports one by one to pinpoint the warning source. Or try some scikit-examples without the tpot import. The only source of that seems like the first import - `from tpot import TPOTClassifier`. Make sure that you are using the latest version of that library also.

Comment: @VivekKumar Thank you for the input. I had actually tried that and the warning appears when running train_test_split from sklearn.model_selection (hence the title). This also occurs in other code where Tpot isn't present.

Comment: Which version of scikit-learn are you using?